# Why is bind being called in my RecyclerView when I click a button for the first time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, facebook-sdk-4.0, share-button

I have a `RecyclerView` where each `ViewHolder` contains a nested Linear Layout with some `TextViews` and a button. (The button is a Facebook `ShareButton` but I see the same behavior with a regular `Button` as well.) When I click the `ShareButton` once, nothing happens. When I click it again, it is successful.

Some clues:

1. Other answers on stackoverflow say to set the button's `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to false -- this has not made a difference in my case.
2. By using some print statements, I see that the first time I click the button, it calls `bind` again on each `ViewHolder`.
3. If I minimize the app, then pull it up again, the first click works.

Relevant `bind` code below:

```
public void bind(Plaque plaque) {
    Log.d(TAG, "BINDING!");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) itemView;
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    layout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap map = layout.getDrawingCache();

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(map)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    mShareButton.setShareContent(content);
}
```

When I click `mShareButton` the first time, it just recalls this code (triggering the print statement at the top). When I click it again, it sends the content to Facebook, as it's supposed to do.
Any ideas how to get it to work the first time, without calling `bind` again?

Comment: where is this method called? ViewHolder - itemView.setOnClickListener() or in BindViewHolder()?

Comment: It's part of the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. It's not part of `onBindViewHolder` and it's not in an `onClick` or a `setOnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure why the `bind` method was being called when my button was clicked. But I was able to avoid this by moving all of the button logic out of the `bind` method and into the ViewHolder constructor method. I also switched to using `ShareDialog` within a regular `Button` so that I could have more control over the `onClick`.